# How autosave (Without dialog box) an .wav file using actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to automatically save the .wav file to location. Currently I am using

```
private function recordComplete(e:Event):void
    {
        fileReference.save(recorder.output, "recording.wav");

    }
```

but It opens dialog box and ask to save the file. How do I save file automatically ? at some Location ? also with different name what I want.
Your help will be appreciable
Thank you

Comment: can we store to same file to some server? for eg. Red5 server

Answer (score 0):

For security concerns, the Flash Player is not allowed to save files on the user filesystem without explicit user consent. This is done because a Flash Player animation can be embedded (and thus executed) on a web page; allowing to save files without user confirmation would allow malicious code to download harmful content on the user computer.

In AIR, the [*File*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [*FileStream*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) classes allow you to create an autosaving system; but, since it's AIR, it would not be usable in a webapp, and your application must be installed before beeing used.

If you just need to regularly save data that the user doesn't need to access directly, I recommend that you look into the [*SharedObject*](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) class. This class allows you to save persistent data without user consent, but this data is not (easily) accessible by the user out of your application.

Comment: Thank you for reply. What I want to do is, I want to get user's feedback and store this to server. I am doing same in case of Video recording, But in case of video, I am using Red5 Server, It directly save the file to stream folder in WebApps. Can we have something like that ?

Comment: Wow. Your question was truly unclear, if it was what you where searching for. From what you where saying, I thought that you were asking to save data on the user computer. You should try rewriting your question (or asking a new one) to be more clear. Red5 may already allows what your searching for, so don't hesitate to add it to the question's tags.

Comment: Actually I want to get the user's feedback in audio and video format. So for video format I am using Red5 Server and it stores its output in streams folder of WebApps. Same thing I want to do with Audio recording feedback. I want to save the recorder audio directly to server. I am using code mention above.  It ask the recorder file to store somewhere on user's machine. But I want to store that file directly to server without showing the dialog box. and want to store it to server. Is it possible ? How?

Comment: However I can upload the wav files to server with any server side scripting like php etc. But for that I just want to store the file without asking to user

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem 
Used following code for upload the file

```
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest ( 'uploadWav.php' );
        var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        request.contentType = 'application/octet-stream';
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.data = recorder.output;
        loader.load( request );
```

instead of using

```
fileReference.save(recorder.output, "recording.wav");
```

and for above code also imported following classes

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
```